# qt47-webkit-devel installation conflicts?

Tags: centos6, make, qt

I'm receiving several conflicts while trying to install `qt47-webkit-devel` on a CentOS 6.4 server, the meat of the conflicts is here:

```
--> Processing Conflict: 1:qt47-x11-4.7.2-1_18.el6.x86_64 conflicts qt-x11 < 1:4.7.2-1_18.el6
--> Processing Conflict: 1:qt47-x11-4.7.2-1_18.el6.x86_64 conflicts qt4-x11 < 1:4.7.2-1_18.el6
--> Processing Conflict: 1:qt47-x11-4.7.2-1_18.el6.x86_64 conflicts phonon < 4.3.80-1
--> Processing Conflict: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.2-1_18.el6.x86_64 conflicts qt4-devel < 1:4.7.2-1_18.el6
--> Processing Conflict: 1:qt47-devel-4.7.2-1_18.el6.x86_64 conflicts phonon-devel < 4.3.80-1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: qt47-devel conflicts with 1:qt-devel-4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64
Error: qt47-x11 conflicts with 1:qt-x11-4.6.2-26.el6_4.x86_64
```

And a pastebin is here: http://pastebin.com/YwF6gvfx

If someone could help me resolve this I'd be much appreciated

Comment: Where did you get these packages?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I answered my own question after thinking on it a minute. Plus one for the problematic package question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was

```
yum remove qt-x11 qt qt4 qt4-x11 phonon
yum install qt47 qt47-x11 qt47-webkit qt47-webkit-devel --enablerepo=atrpms-testing
```

ATRPMS.repo

```
[atrpms]
name=CentOS #releasever – #basearch – ATrpms
baseurl=http://dl.atrpms.net/el$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/stable
gpgkey=http://ATrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1

[atrpms-testing]
name=CentOS #releasever – #basearch – ATrpms testing
baseurl=http://dl.atrpms.net/el$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/testing
gpgkey=http://ATrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```